# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start Exception for different user

Tags: c#, exe

I created an exe application with a button which has the following code executed when clicked. It is working when clicked by the same user which is used to create the exe. But the same exe when clicked by other users get exception message as `"Application not found"`. Also the stack trace looks like given below.

```
        try
        {                
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://google.com");
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Exception:

```
    Exception Info: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo)
   at MyTool.MainWindow.MyButton_Click(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the other users that are running your .exe don't have a default browser or application to run this command. You can validate my theory if you execute the command in Run (Windows+R) and you encounter an error.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to start application named "https://google.com". You need to start web-browser application with parameter as URL:

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", "https://google.com");
```

Or with other application name.